# validating using input.value.match in javascript

Tags: javascript, validation

I believe I have a fairly simple problem, but I am unfortunately unable to resolve it. I have searched for a while and tried several different variations of this code but cannot seem to get it to work.

All I am trying to do is check and see if my input value has a alpha character in it opposed to a number.

Here is my js function:

```
function checkLetters(input) {
    var numOnly = /^[0-9]+$/;
    var hasLetters = false;
    if (!input.value.match(numOnly)) {
        hasLetters = true;
    } 
    return hasLetters;
}
```

and here is the code calling it:

```
<input type="text" name="cc_number" size="13" maxlength="11" onblur="
    if(checkLength(cc_number.value) == true) {
    alert('Sorry, that is not a valid number - Credit Card numbers must be nine digits!');
    } else if (checkLetters(cc_number.value) == true) {
    alert('Credit Card number must be numbers only, please re-enter the CC number using numbers only.');
    }">
```

Any help or suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: Oh my, I'm sorry, what a noobie, I forgot the most important part.
I get an error that says "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'match' of undefined. I see this when inspecting element and stepping through the if statement in the checkLetters funtion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're passing `cc_number.value` as `input`, but then referencing `input.value.match()`, which works out to:

```
cc_number.value.value.match();
```

Just pass `cc_number`:

```
if (checkLetters(cc_number)) {
  ...
}
```

Comment: That worked, thank you so much, I have been fooling with this for so long. I really appreciate the help.

Comment: you can also put the regexp in the input itself using the pattern attribute to provide more accessible and no-js validation.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you're trying to validate credit card input. May I suggest a different approach?

```
function checkCardInput(input,errorId) {
  var errorNoticeArea = document.getElementById(errorId);   
  errorNoticeArea.innerHTML = ''; 
  if(!input.value) {
    errorNoticeArea.innerHTML = 'This field cannot be left blank.';   
    return;
  }
  if(!input.value.match(/[0-9]/)) {
    errorNoticeArea.innerHTML = 'You may only enter numbers in this field.';
    input.value = '';
    return; 
  }
  if(input.value.length != 9) {
    errorNoticeArea.innerHTML = 'Credit card numbers must be exactly 9 digits long.';   
    return;
  }
}
```

See **[this jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3tFfZ/)** for an example use.